# Difference between python boto get_contents_to_filename and s3 cp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, aws-cli

I copy files from AWS S3 to my local file system. From an I/O perspective, what's the difference between using `get_contents_to_filename`http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html from the boto module versus the CLI `aws s3 cp` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html command itself? Is one faster or more recommended than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws s3 cp` is using the Boto3/botocore library internally but written efficiently. From I/O perspective for large number of files, the CLI will be faster since I believe it handles buffered I/O efficiently than if you do using Boto3. I am not aware any benchmark/tests that compares the efficiency of these methods.